# Showing results python command to the web cgi

Tags: python, cgi, cgi-bin

I have a python script and it runs well if executed in a terminal or command line , but after I try even internal server error occurred . how to enhance the script to be run on the web.

HTML

```
<html><body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/coba5.py" method="post">
<p>File: <input type="file" name="file"></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Upload"></p>
</form>
</body></html>
```

PYTHON

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import cgi, os
import cgitb; cgitb.enable()
import simplejson as json
import optparse
import sys

try: # Windows needs stdio set for binary mode.
    import msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode (0, os.O_BINARY) # stdin  = 0
    msvcrt.setmode (1, os.O_BINARY) # stdout = 1
except ImportError:
    pass

form = cgi.FieldStorage()

# A nested FieldStorage instance holds the file
fileitem = form['file']
fn = os.path.basename(fileitem.filename)
data = open('/tmp/upload-cgi/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
data=fileitem.file.read()
location_database = open('/home/bioinformatics2/DW/taxo.json', 'r')
database = json.load(location_database)

for line in data: 
 for taxonomy in database:  
  if taxonomy["genus"] == line.replace('\n','') :
   print "Kingdom: %s," % taxonomy['kingdom'],
   print "phylum: %s," % taxonomy['phylum'],
   print "class: %s," % taxonomy['class'],
   print "order: %s," % taxonomy['order'],
   print "family: %s," % taxonomy['family'],
   print "genus: %s" % taxonomy['genus']
   break
 else:
  print ("No found genus on taxanomy")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not outputting the HTTP header.  At a minimum, you need to output:

```
print "Content-Type: text/plain"
print ""
```

You are also reading the file twice:

```
data = open('/tmp/upload-cgi/' + fn, 'wb').write(fileitem.file.read())
data=fileitem.file.read()
```

The second `fileitem.file.read()` will probably not read any content, since the file should already be at the end-of-file, and so `data` will be empty.

Comment: I tried to add `print "Content-Type: text/plain"` it above `print "Kingdom: %s," % taxonomy['kingdom'],` but still the same error

Comment: You need both lines - the `Content-Type` line and the blank line.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the output from running the script on the command line and, if you have access to it, the error output from the web server's error log

Comment: *output from running the script on the command line* is blank white?

Comment: blank white results from the web , if from the command line work and generate an output value

Comment: Please see edited question.  You are reading the file twice, so the second time will receive no content.

Comment: I tried again and the results appear no error but its results are not accurate,